# Why bootstrap modal not hiding its popup

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Here i'm using Angular with Bootstrap here when i Click on * Icon or click on CLOSE button why modal not hiding

```
<div class="modal" id="modalSuccess">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <button class="close"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalSuccess">&times;</button>
                <h4 style="color:green">{{msg}}</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" value="Close" ng-click="okCloseBtn()" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Angular.Js**

```
$scope.okCloseBtn = function () {
        alert('in closer')
       $('#modalSuccess').modal('hide');
}
```

Here alert is working please give me answer where I'm doing wrong

Comment: are you using bootstrap directives or plain bootstrap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `$modalInstance`

```
 $scope.okCloseBtn = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
```

Comment: are you using bootstrap dependency?